# Ignore all current migrations and start from current model state WITHOUT deleting the migration files/history

Tags: django, django-migrations

*Preface: Migrating from Oracle to Postgres with a VERY large, VERY old Django app.*

Need the ability to start a new db from the current state of my models, ignoring 5+ years of migrations, BUT without deleting any of the migration files.

Comment: Perhaps [Squashing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) is what you want to do? Your old migration files will stay but you would have a set of extra migration files that are made after squashing all your previous migrations into one (or sometimes a few) migration files.

Comment: You can specify a number like `./manage.py migrate someapp 0002` to run migrations to a certain point. Move the migration files out of the folder, do your migration, move them back. This would be a bad solution but I guess you need it for testing anyway

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat didn't want to do that since that creates another can of worms, there are 5+ years of migrations, meaning, apps have been added, removed, dependency order have changed, adding squashing to the mix is not viable, i will spend days retroactively fixing it all, and still not what i wanted (see my answer). Ps. i tried this once, spent hours pulling my hair, i was in pure dependency order hell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use Django, and have it do it all for me.

1. create the database using a fake connection using all the variables from `default`. Changed `USER` to `postgres` since it's the only user that can access the database `postgres` and `NAME` to `postgres` for the previous reason. ('main' i called it, it's only used the once, to create the database)
2. figure out what the path of my app was, loop over all my apps and if the app was local to my path, create a temporary `migrations_<random>` folder inside the app path, and a `__init__.py` inside that. finally, update `MIGRATION_MODULES` telling django where to find the migration folder for said app.
3. call `./manage.py makemigrations`, and make them. (remember this will use the migrations from `MIGRATION_MODULES`)
4. call `./manage.py migrate`, and apply them. (remember this will use the migrations from `MIGRATION_MODULES`)
5. delete ALL migrations in the `django_migrations` table
6. (clean up) set `MIGRATION_MODULES` to it's original state, delete all the `migrations_<random>` folders created in all the apps.
7. call `./manage.py migrate --fake` to "apply" all the existing migrations you have in the project

enjoy!

```
import inspect
import os
import tempfile
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import connection, connections
from contextlib import ExitStack
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder


def create_database_and_models():

    settings.DATABASES['main'] = settings.DATABASES['default'].copy()
    settings.DATABASES['main']['USER'] = 'postgres'
    settings.DATABASES['main']['NAME'] = 'postgres'

    with connections['main'].cursor() as cursor:
        database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
        cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE %s' % (database_name,))
        print('Create db %s' % (database_name))

    original_migration_modules = settings.MIGRATION_MODULES.copy()
    project_path = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        # Find each app that belongs to the user and are not in the site-packages. Create a fake temporary
        # directory inside each app that will tell django we don't have any migrations at all.
        for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
            module = app_config.module
            app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(module)))

            if app_path.startswith(project_path):
                temp_dir = stack.enter_context(tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix='migrations_', dir=app_path))
                # Need to make this directory a proper python module otherwise django will refuse to recognize it
                open(os.path.join(temp_dir, '__init__.py'), 'a').close()
                settings.MIGRATION_MODULES[app_config.label] = '%s.%s' % (app_config.module.__name__,
                                                                          os.path.basename(temp_dir))

        # create brand new migrations in fake migration folders local to the app
        call_command('makemigrations')
        # call migrate as normal, this will just read those fake folders with migrations in them.
        call_command('migrate')

        # delete all the migrations applied, remember these where NOT the real migrations from the project
        MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all().delete()

    settings.MIGRATION_MODULES = original_migration_modules

    # Fake all the current migrations in the project
    call_command('migrate', fake=True)
```

Comment: While this solution works, it is a one-off solution which will have to be repeated after you'll stumble upon this situation yet again. I advise looking at solutions in my answer for a long-term ones.

Comment: Yup, thats just what is for, one-off. Create a db and all the structure around it without relying on your current migrations. The reason why i wouldn't care about custom `RunPython` / `RunSQL` from previous migrations is that there is a next step to this: loop over all the models from the old db and copy it over to the new db. So in reality, is about creating a structure first, and then copying over the data 1:1 from one place to another using django. Why? because oracle is shit and renames columns/tables/..etc making migrations a PITA

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to "start fresh" when creating database in PostgreSQL, but still be able to use (or even update) your migrations on old Oracle database, if necessary. I can think of 3 options to achieve that:

#### Squashing the migrations

This can, to some extent, be handled by Django itself, but Django will not always be correct about everything and it will actually leave some things to fix them manually, like any `RunPython` operations.

By simply invoking `./manage.py squashmigrations`, you can ask Django to create an alternative migration to all old migrations you've had before. If any of the previous migrations are applied on your database, Django will just ignore the squashed migration that tries to replace them and will continue applying the old ones, but when none of the migrations replaced by squashed one are applied, Django will ignore old migrations and just apply the squashed one, treating it as a quicker way to achieve the same database state.

#### Creating a replacement (squashed migration) for existing migrations manually

This solution comes with understanding of what actually happens under the hood when you're squashing migrations in Django and it's very similar to the squashing process, but achieved in a different way.

Under the hood, when you try to squash migrations, Django will create a migration that just contains all the steps from all previous migrations (with some optimizations applied, if possible) and will add a special field `replaces` in the `Migration` class inside, containing a list of old migrations that were squashed.

This means that you can create your own migration that should replace a list of other ones. **This is an advanced usage of migration system, so proceed with care!** To achieve that:

1. Make sure that your current model state is fully represented in Django migrations. To check that, run `./manage.py makemigrations YOUR_APP_NAME --dry-run` and make sure it returns `No changes detected in app 'YOUR_APP_NAME'`.
2. Temporarily move all migrations that you want to replace outside of migrations directory, so Django is not aware of their existence
3. Run `./manage.py migrate YOUR_APP_NAME` to generate a new migration that replaces the old ones
4. Add `replaces = [...]` attribute at the top of `Migration` class in newly created migration, replacing three dots with a list of all migrations this migration shall replace (to get that list, you can create a squashed migration beforehand just to copy the `replaces` field from it)
5. Make sure the new migration name doesn't conflict with any of the old ones. You can just change it's name now without any problems, even if this is the initial migration (names of the migrations doesn't matter, they just need to be referenced properly by other migrations when necessary, you can even get rid of the migration number)
6. Move old migrations back to your migrations directory
7. Make sure that migrations are still creating the same state of the database as before, by invoking ./manage.py makemigrations YOUR_APP_NAME --dry-run`.

Note that for this solution (as for automatically created squash migration) you need to have one replacement migration per consistent sequence (or graph) of migration files. That means if you for example want to replace migrations from 0002 to 0008, keep 0009 and replace 0010 to 0012, you will need 2 replacement migrations, one per the sequence range. Same goes for a "graph" of migrations (if you for example have two 0004 migrations and a merging migration 0005) accordingly.

For both of the above options, Django will use old migration files when at least one of the old migrations is already applied on your database and will use the new one if none of them is applied. Every migration created after the squash migration will be used in both cases.

#### Keeping a separate migration lists for your databases.

It is also possible to just separate both migration lists by keeping them in separate directories. Django allows you to overwrite the default location for migration files, per app basis, by using [`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#migration-modules) setting. Note that the migrations will be completely separate, so you will need to manually keep them both in sync. When doing some changes in your app models, you will need to run `./manage.py makemigrations` twice, changing `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting between the runs or you will have to copy the migration over from one location to another. I highly advise against this solution as it is very easy to mess up the synchronization between migration lists and it has no benefit from the other methods except of the situation when you for some reason need the old process when recreating the Oracle database from scratch (you still can use the old method, but you will have to invoke one of the old migrations manually in such case).

Comment: Hint: you can delete the old migrations in the first and the second solution after you are sure that all of your databases have all of the old migrations applied. You can also get rid of `replaces` field in the new migration either, after checking that it is present in the `django_migrations` table, to include it in the another squash.

Comment: I'm intimately aware of how squash migrations work, i wrote this: https://pypi.org/project/django-squash/ i've been meaning to get it merged into django proper but haven't had the time. The issue with the quash solution is that it uses `replaces = [..]`, that plus `dependencies = [..]` and a 5+ year project leads to a lot of BAD migrations that happen in the past that wont fly currently and you get broken nodes and `migrate` just yells at you. Nonetheless thank you for your write up, it will definitely educate the next person coming looking for this information.