# How to initialize Django database without using existing migrations?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a Django project, which contains dozens of migrations, and I want to initialize it on a new database. How do I do this without running all the migrations, which can take a lot of time to run?

In earlier versions of Django, it used to have a "syncdb" command that you could run to create all tables in a blank database, bypassing all migrations.

Current Django's `migrate` command has a `--run-syncdb` option, but the docs say:

```
Creates tables for apps without migrations.
```

Since all my apps have migrations, I interpret this to mean it does nothing in my case.

Does modern Django no longer have anyway to initialize a database without tediously running through every single migration?

Note, I'm not asking how to initialize a Django database. I'm asking how to do it more efficiently than by running migrations, which are designed to modify an existing database, not initialize one from scratch.

This has to be possible, since the unittest framework has the option to initialize the test database schema without running migrations.

Comment: You could remove all the migrations and then run the syncdb option

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe That's not an option. It's part of a multi-tenant application. I still need to maintain migrations for other databases.

Comment: you can run ```./manage.py migrate --fake```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this functionality isn't in Django, but I found [this clever post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821064/) that works around it by temporarily changing the location of the migration directory to an empty temp dir, re-running makemigrations to create a single initial migration for all apps, running those, reverting the files, and then faking the real migrations.

The only flaw is that their code assumes no migrations in external packages. I modified it to work with apps stored anywhere, locally or in your virtualenv:

```
import inspect
import os
import tempfile
from contextlib import ExitStack

from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder


original_migration_modules = settings.MIGRATION_MODULES.copy()
project_path = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

with ExitStack() as stack:
    # Find each app that belongs to the user and are not in the site-packages. Create a fake temporary
    # directory inside each app that will tell django we don't have any migrations at all.
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        module = app_config.module
        app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(module)))
        migrations_path = os.path.join(app_path, 'migrations')

        if os.path.isdir(migrations_path):
            temp_dir = stack.enter_context(tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix='migrations_', dir=app_path))
            # Need to make this directory a proper python module otherwise django will refuse to recognize it
            with open(os.path.join(temp_dir, '__init__.py'), 'a') as fout:
                pass
            settings.MIGRATION_MODULES[app_config.label] = '{}.{}'.format(
                app_config.module.__name__,
                os.path.basename(temp_dir),
            )

    # create brand new migrations in fake migration folders local to the app
    call_command('makemigrations')
    # call migrate as normal, this will just read those fake folders with migrations in them.
    call_command('migrate')

    # delete all the migrations applied, remember these where NOT the real migrations from the project
    MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all().delete()

settings.MIGRATION_MODULES = original_migration_modules

# Fake all the current migrations in the project
call_command('migrate', fake=True)
```